# Catch a event when the statusBar opens (iOS 9)

Tags: swift, widget, ios9, statusbar, today-extension

I need to update the information in today extension in iOS 9 from the target application. The best time to do this is when the user drags the statusBar to open a window with widgets and notifications. How can this event be recognized?

Answer (score 0):

The `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol has an `applicationWillResignActive` method that call just at the right time.